# Would my data structure and querying be viable in RavenDB?

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

We have an issue with our data structure in SQL Server as we are ordering by a calculated field.  With this in mind we were wondering if it would be possible to use map reduce to prepare indexes to keep our responses snappy - specifically within RavenDB.

FYI - I asked this previously on DBA and got some great answers but wanted to consider this different approach:

I will try and give an example - this is not my table structure - I'm simply trying to outline the issue in order to find a solution...

Person Id, Name

BrothersNames Id, Name

SistersNames Id, Name

PersonBrothers (join table) PersonId, BrotherNameId

PersonSisters (join table) PersonId, SisterNameId

OK - so imagine this database holds every person from a small country. The database holds a record of the names of everyone's brothers and sisters (it does not map a person to their brother or sister - just their names) so that we can find out statistics about names.

Obviously lots of names are shared so currently in SQL Server the join tables normalise this for us.

What I want to do is take one user and find out the number of matches of brother's names and number of matches of sister's names with every other user in the system, then add those two matches together and order by that descending. So this would give us a list of users who have the most number of brothers and sister's names in common.

I'm really only interested in the top ten matches but I think I have to get the whole result set to work out the top ten matches.

Please note that in my actual data a person can have a million brothers or a milllion sisters. This is where I'm getting performance issues.

This is how I'm calculating the matches for brothers and I do the same for sisters

```
select p.id, matches
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS Matches,
        pbn.PersonId
        FROM PersonBrothersNames pbn
        INNER JOIN Brothersnames bn on pbn.BrothernameId =bn.Id
        inner join PersonBrothersName otherpbn on otherpbn.BrothernameId = bn.Id

        WHERE pbn.PersonId= @PersonId and pbn.PersonId <> otherpbn.personid
        GROUP BY  pbn.PersonId

    ) As BrothersNamesJoin ON BrothersNamesJoin.Person = p.Id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is something like this:

```
     { "Name": "a", "Brothers": ["b","c"] }
```

Then you can index them, and use the More Like This bundle to search for the other people with similar brothers names.
And yes, it will rank them for you.

Comment: If one person can have a 1.5 million brothers (I know that's impossible in real life) will this still respond quickly with a More Like This index?

Comment: Yes, because it doesn't handle this in the same manner. It does comparison over vectors of similarities.

Comment: As always, you got to test. I haven't tested it with 1.5 mil, but it was tested with large amounts of data

Comment: Thanks Ayende - will test and comment here later

Comment: We have tried saving a document with 1.5 mil entries in as stated in your answer (each is a long) and the Silverlight app is not responsive.  Is this becuase Raven can not manage such large docs or is this a silverlight client limitation? We will try querying direct...

Comment: Victoria, what is the actual _size_ of this document? Please note that is likely to be several dozen MB, which likely won't work very well within the text box.

Comment: That should still _work_, but the SL text box is just not meant for handling that much data.

Comment: Ok thanks again for your response.  I will test direct to Raven and post results

Comment: Thanks - we tested but with that so many records it was slow even without using silverlight.  I think we need to restructure the data

Comment: Whilst I previously had slow results I retried this with the newest stable Raven and worked a lot better.  Is working fine but I have a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812423/aggregating-morelikethis-results-in-ravendb)